# My eclipse neon1 is not working

Tags: c++, eclipse, error-handling, mingw, eclipse-neon

Even, the simple 'Hello world!' c++ project isn't working.
I get these errors:

```
Program "g++" not found in PATH
Program "gcc" not found in PATH
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved
Symbol 'endl' could not be resolved
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved
```

I tried reinstalling everything. Mingw, eclipse, I even have the right java version.
I also looked across previous question, but couldn't find a solution.
MinGW is also added to te environment variables:
MINGW_HOME  C:\Program Files(x86)\ CodeBlocks\MinGW

Could anyone help me, please!

Comment: Please post error messages as verbatim text not as images.

Comment: `MINGW_HOME` != `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

You must include the location of *gcc* and *g++* in your `PATH` environment variable, so that the compiler can be found and called. Based on how you have set `MINGW_HOME`, you would need to add `C:\Program Files(x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin` to your `PATH` (note the `bin` folder in addition to MinGW home, this is where *gcc* and *g++* are situated in MinGW).

You can also define environment variables that are only visible in Eclipse by going to *Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Environment*.